# What is the necessity to universalise a law?

Tags: soft-question, models, foundations, laws-of-physics

What are the necessary conditions or observations that are required for universalisation of a law? I am not good at English so by **universalise** I mean to claim something to be universal. So how can anyone claim a law to be universal while just performing an experiment on earth? How can one claim a law to be universal or to be valid in whole universe?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "universalize", and what do you mean when you say "law"?

Comment: I have never heard the term universalize

Comment: There is no law 'universalized' standing on earth, be specific

Comment: I think by "universalize" he means "generalize".

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for explaining them

Comment: With the word "generalize" this is a fair *philosophical* question going to the heart of all physical sciences: how do we know that , say, Coulomb's law of $F=q_1q_2/r^2$ observed and measured here on earth holds equally in the middle of Galaxy. Of course, we do not *know* it but we do have other observations that are consistent with it, for example, the behavior of atomic emission spectra, Maxwell's theory of EM propagation, etc.

Comment: @hyportnex I am not good at English so please edit my question to make it convenient for all.

Comment: Physics works this way, *you find some phenomenon* -> *make assumptions (axioms and postulates)* -> *Explain it with your theory* -> *your theory seems to predict other natural phenomenons * -> *you find a flaw* -> *you fix it by changing the assumption models*. Even the universal law of gravitation, law of conservation of energy, etc were not perfect, they had flaws in it, which modern physics polished, still, it needs to be polished more! If it's perfect, then *combine theories and then generalize them*.

Answer (score 2):

Universal laws are preferred in physics because they do not require the handing of special cases and exceptions.

So local laws such as "bowling balls fall faster than feathers" or "the sky is blue" are much less useful than universal laws such as "light travels at $3\times 10^8$ metres per second in a vacuum" or "every pair of objects attracts each other with a force that is proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them".

Of course we cannot be absolutely sure that these "universal" laws are truly universal, but they are consistent with the outcomes of all our experiments and observations, not just on Earth but elsewhere too (e.g. when astronaut David Scott dropped a hammer and a feather on the Moon).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need in physics for laws to be universal. It just happens to be the case that the laws of physics seem to be universal. However, universality has to be verified by observation. As an example: the absorption lines of hydrogen are observable over vast distances across the universe. And it can be seen that hydrogen “behaves” exactly the same everywhere in the universe, like on earth. As far as I now there are no observations that indicate that the laws as found on earth differ from the ones *observed* in other regions of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing specific is required.  All that is required is that someone frames the proposed law sufficiently well, then claims it is universal, and then people think up experiments which it can pass or fail.  If & when it fails them it's clearly not universal, so long as it passes them it may be.